# Where is the zone.js file in @angularCli RC0?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I came across this question today that how `@angular/cli` 1 RC 0 is working without `zone.js` file .

How it is detecting changes and updating UI ?

I tried to look for the `@angular/cli` documentation but did not find a convincing answer. This angular is changing with such a fast pace that it is really hard to cop-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [quick-start project](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html), it has a file `polyfills.ts` which contains

```ts
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

The `polyfills.ts` is configured in `.angular-cli.json`

```json
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks !!  I missed it but now I see it.